# "Subject" and "predicate" in sentences starting with "there"?

Tags: subjects, predicate

A third grade student has been asked to find out the **subject** and the **predicate** in the sentence:

> **There are a book and a pen on the table.**

[Here,](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/oddness-when-you-start-a-sentence-with-there-is)  it says that the real subject is **"a book and a pen"** but I know that **"there"** can also be called a **"dummy subject".**

What should be the most suitable **subject** and **predicate** in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The real subject "there" because it's involved in the subject-auxiliary inversion and used in a question tag:

Subject-auxiliary inversion:

> **Are there** a book and a pen on the table?

Question tag:

> There are a book and a pen on the table, **aren't there**?

"A book and a pen" is a **displaced subject**. A displaced subject is not syntactically a subject, but it semantically corresponds to the subject in the non-existential counterpart.

Comment: And the predicate is everything except the "there"?

Comment: Yes @user100323

Comment: and the same thing applies to the the sentences starting with "it"?

Comment: @user100323 For example?

Comment: for example, "it is a  pleasure working with you"

Comment: Yes, @user100323, in an "extraposition" construction like that, the subject is realized by the dummy "it".